# Can we enlarge the facebook like button or change the color?

Tags: facebook-like

can we enlarge the Facebook like button? 
like the width and the height... scale...
Can we change the colors?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`Like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you will see that you can change the width of the button.  There are a few variations that you can change here with regards the appearance and colour too.

Comment: I need to enlarge the width and height of the Button not the plugin (i want a bigger "hand")

Comment: You mean the "thumbs up" on the Like button?

Comment: I would advise that you create your own image and hook it up to the Facebook code.